# C++ store any child struct/class in array?

Tags: c++

In C++ I have a series of structures defined...

```
struct Component {};
struct SceneGraphNode : Component {};
struct Renderable : Component {};
struct Health : Component {};
```

These could easily be classes, I've been told that there is very little difference in C++.

In Java it is possible to declare an array of type `Component` and put any class that extends from (inherits) `Component` into it. Java considers them all components and since everything uses smart pointers, Java's "array" is really just a list of smart-pointers which are all the same size.

However I understand that Java handles arrays significantly different from C++. When I checked the size of each of these structs I got the following.

```
Component                   // 4
SceneGraphNode : Component  // 8
Renderable : Component      // 8
Health : Component          // 20
```

Which isn't suprising. Now when I create an array of Components, the size of the blocks are obviously going to be 4 (bytes) which won't hold any of the other structures.

So my question is, how can I store a loose list of `Components` (IE a list that can store any class / struct that inherits from Component)? In Java this is mind-numbingly simple to do. Surely there must be an easy way in C++ to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to have a Base class pointer to a child class object, ie
`Component * sgn = new SceneGraphNode`

So allocate an array of `Component*`s (or a vector if it needs to vary in size) and make each entry point to a derived object.

```
Component * components[100];
components[0] = new SceneGraphNode;
components[1] = new Renderable;
// so on and so on
```

In addition to this you must have virtual functions in Component for any member function you intend to define in the child classes

```
class Component {
    public:
        virtual void method() = 0;
        virtual int method2(int arg) = 0;
};

class SceneGraphNode : public Component {
    public:
        virtual void method(){
            //body
        }
        virtual int method2(int arg){
            return arg*2;
        }
};
```

The `virtual` keyword makes it so that at runtime it looks at the actual type of the pointed to object and calls its method, rather than calling the pointer types method.  This is how java does things normally.  The `= 0` makes the function "pure virtual" meaning that a child class **must** define that method.  Using our array defined above...

```
components[0]->method();
compenents[2]->method2(1);
```

If you would prefer a vector to an array, you can replace the array version with:

```
#include <vector>;
//...
std::vector<Component* > components;
components.push_back(new SceneGraphNode);
components.push_back(new Renderable);
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about the need to define the methods as virtual. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you store them as follow

```
std::vector<Component *> components;
Component * c = new Health;
components.push_back( c );
```

calling    `components[0] -> method();` will invoke `method()` of `Health`

This is how polymorphism is done in C++.

Also make sure `method()` of Component is `virtual`

Comment: ``std::vector<Component *> components;`` That will leak memory, use a smart pointer, either shared_ptr or unique_ptr

Answer (score 1):

You can store a `vector` of smart pointers that points to base class objects, then you can add derived class obejects into it.

For example:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component> > base;
 Component.push_back( std_unique_ptr<Component>(new SceneGraphNode()) ); 
            //^^use correct constructor, this example just show the methodology
 Component.push_back( std_unique_ptr<Component>(new Renderable()) );
```